# AVAudioSession mix with WKWebview

Tags: ios, objective-c, wkwebview, voip, avaudiosession

I am working on a VoIP app. For that I had set the category of AVAudioSession to `AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord`.

All the app functionality was working fine till now.

Then we had a new requirement where within app when the voice call is going on, user can play one video embedded in WKWebView.

Now when user plays video from WKWebView, video plays successfully and the volume of video is also as expected. But when user stops/pauses the video then voice call gets disconnected.

So I came to know that WKWebView runs in different process than the app, so in order to make my app's audio mixable with WKWebview I have to set the AVAudioSession as mixwithOthers.

I have done that with the following code...

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *errorInSettingCategory;
BOOL success = [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions: AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionDefaultToSpeaker | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:&errorInSettingCategory];
```

Now after playing video form WKWebView I am able continue with my voice call.

But this approach introduced the new bug.

As now the AVAudioSession is mixable, volume of the video from WKWebView is quite low and app's audio (voice call audio) is quite dominant.

I have tried different setcategory options but with no luck.

I want to have volume of app's audio and volume of WKWebView's video at same level.

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the `duckOthers` property of your AVAudioSession to `false`:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avaudiosession/categoryoptions/1616618-duckothers